# httpbin.org/get request keep on called in Reacts application

Tags: reactjs, https

Can any one explain why a get request kept on called in Reacts application. Refer the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution, I was using a npm package "react-detect-offline" to render components based on online and offline status, that was triggering a request to check the same.

Answer (score 0):

if possible could you please expand upon your question a little more, like maybe an example of your code that's making the request?

(I don't have enough rep to post comments)

Comment: I am not manually calling it, this call is made automatically in react Application. Wanted to know is this a default behavior of React Application.